# leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a step in Robot Framework to check if duration > 20 minutes then failed.

What to fix when the actual minute is 09 with zero ? no issue if it is 10,11....

error:  `Evaluating expression '09 > 20' failed: SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers (<string>, line 1)`

Test step:

```
Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Run Keyword If   ${modelTrainedDuration} > ${minutes}   fail    Model Trained Duration is more than ${minutes} minutes
```

Comment: Maybe you can use string? like int('09') ?

Comment: Why are the durations being interpreted (literally) as integers? Typing 03 in the Python console is an error, same for `x = 03`, but `x= int('03')` is valid.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use double quotes in a variable, it will solve your problem

```
Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Run Keyword If   "${modelTrainedDuration}" > "${minutes}"   fail    Model Trained Duration is more than ${minutes} minutes
```

Comment: Comparing numbers as strings won't always give you the results you expect. For example, `"100" > "20"` will return `False`

Comment: this help to resolve the problem. thanks!